# Mutable default argument usage

Tags: python

I have a function that returns a ChromeDriver instance and logs browser information only once in a session:

```
from selenium import webdriver
def init_chromedriver(path, timeout=30, _l=[]):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(timeout)
    if not _l:
        _l.append(None)
        logger = logging.getLogger('driver')
        for k, v in driver.capabilities.items():
            logger.log(logging.INFO, f"{k}: {v}")
    return driver
```

Is it a good practice or should I use another method?

Comment: Is this actually your code? Cause `some_args` isn't used, and I doubt you'd be using `webdriver.Chrome(...)`. If it's not, then please include your actual code.

Comment: Peilonrayz, thank you for your comment. I have added my actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global flag would be clear and simple:

```
_LOGGED_DRIVER = False

def init_chromedriver(path, timeout=30):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(timeout)
    global _LOGGED_DRIVER
    if not _LOGGED_DRIVER:
        _LOGGED_DRIVER = True
        logger = logging.getLogger('driver')
        for k, v in driver.capabilities.items():
            logger.log(logging.INFO, f"{k}: {v}")
    return driver
```

Alternatively, you could replace the function after it has been called for the first time:

```
def _init_chromedriver(path, timeout=30):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(timeout)
    return driver

def init_chromedriver(path, timeout=30):
    driver = _init_chromedriver(path, timeout)
    logger = logging.getLogger('driver')
    for k, v in driver.capabilities.items():
        logger.log(logging.INFO, f"{k}: {v}")
    global init_chromedriver
    init_chromedriver = _init_chromedriver
    return driver
```

But I think the global flag would be clearer.